# How do you pass a generic type ('Object myVar') as a parameter to replace a class type ('SomeClass.class')?

Tags: java

How do you pass a class type as parameter?

```
public Configuration getConfig(Object mapper, Object format) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration(false);
    conf.setClass("mapreduce.map.class", TestMapper.class, Mapper.class);
    conf.setClass("mapreduce.inputformat.class", DatastoreInputFormat.class, InputFormat.class);
    return conf;
}
```

I want to replace the value `TestMapper.class` and `DatastoreInputFormat.class` with the parameters `mapper` and `format`, respectively.

I'm not sure how to convert from `Object` to `TestMapper.class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to getConfig() should perhaps have Class type in in the first place instead of Object's. However:

If you want the runtime class of whatever your mapper and format Objects are, just call their .getClass() methods.

```
 conf.setClass("mapreduce.map.class",mapper.getClass(), Mapper.class);
 conf.setClass("mapreduce.inputformat.class",format.getClass(),InputFormat.class);
```

So, if your `mapper` method parameter is actually an instance of TestMapper , mapper.getClass() will return the same object as TestMapper.class does.

If your `mapper` and `parameter` already is the .class objects, i.e. you have called the method as `foo.getConfig(TestMapper.class,DatastoreInputFormat.class);` you can cast your Objects back to a Class object, assuming the conf.setClass() takes `Class<?>` type:

```
conf.setClass("mapreduce.map.class",(Class<?>)mapper, Mapper.class);
conf.setClass("mapreduce.inputformat.class",(Class<?>)format,InputFormat.class);
```

Comment: I believe he means that he already receives `Class` as parameter. Although it is really not so clear... Probably you understood the qestion better.

Comment: That could be, in which case all he needs is to do a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not clear what is the prototype of `Configuration.setClass()`. If it is `Configuration.setClass(String, Class, Class)` you can convert from Object to Class by casting: `(Class)mapper` and (Class)format`.

Although it is a bad style as all casting... Why getConfig() receives Objects? May be it should receive arguments of type Class? In this case you even do not need any casting at all.